# Searching based on dynamic SQL in ASP.NET MVC without using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone give some idea for custom searching? I am looking for a way to implement this logic using ASP.NET MVC.

What I want is either to search for a user who is in Newyork or gender is Male - or also search for a user who is in Newyork and gender is male using AND OR logic with using of 2 radio button one 'AND' another 'OR'. Check my screenshot of client side view:

[image: Client Side View]

Here is my code sample:

`DemoSearchController`:

```
public ActionResult Index(string loactionsearch,string txtGenderSkill)
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        
    string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[LocationInfo] where LocationName like '%" + loactionsearch + "%' AND Gender like '%" + txtGenderSkill + "%'";

    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);

    sqlconn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);

    List<LocationInfo> location = new List<LocationInfo>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        location.Add(new LocationInfo
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt64(dr["ID"]),
                    LocationName = Convert.ToString(dr["LocationName"]),
                    Gender = Convert.ToString(dr["Gender"])
                });
    }

    sqlconn.Close();
    ModelState.Clear();

    return View(location);                       
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<CM_CRUD_BootstrapPopUp.Models.LocationInfo>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DemoSearch", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
                <!--TextBox-->
                <input type="text" id="txtNewMultSkill" name="loactionsearch" placeholder="Enter Location" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">

                <!--Radio Button-->
                <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="AND">
                <label for="html">AND</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="OR">
                <label for="css">OR</label><br>

                <!--TextBox-->
                <input type="text" id="txtGenderSkill" name="gendersearch" placeholder="Enter Gender" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">
                <br />
                <!--SearchButton-->
                <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" />
            </p>

            <div class="col-md-6" id="div_Keyskills">
                <div class="" id="txtKeyskill">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnSkill" />
        </div>
    </div>
   // ....
   // other table view code here
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework's job is to build the SQL command for you. If you're not using EF, that means you need to construct that command string yourself. So you'll need to append "where" clauses as needed. Also, please look into parameterized statements, as your code is open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Google for `Bobby Tables`. Your code is wide open to SQL injection. And overcomplicated. What would happen if someone passed `'; drop table users;--` to `locationsearch`? You don't need a DataAdapter *or* a DataTable if you intend to generate objects from the query results.

Comment: I really would do this in a stored procedure instead of code, where you simply pass in all the optional parameter values: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example

Comment: basically  I used store procudure but this is for demo purpose thats why I called here

Answer (score -1):

Add one more parameter to your method like

```
public ActionResult Index(string loactionsearch, string txtGenderSkill, string concatinator)
{
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

            string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[LocationInfo] where LocationName like '%" + loactionsearch + "%' ";
            sqlquery += concatinator;
            sqlquery += " Gender like '%" + txtGenderSkill + "%'";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
```

Pass AND/OR in this new parameter

this is neither a best approach for dealing with SQL queries nor is the way to work with sensitive data. Please use parameterized queries at least

Comment: WARNING: This code does not address the major security vulnerability in the original code.

Comment: `'; drop table users; --`

Comment: Identification of vulnerabilities is not objective of the post

Comment: Bad code shouldn't be posted as an answer no matter what. Especially when it's so easy to make this *safe* by using a parameter.

Comment: I know what is sql injection this is just demo purpose...I want to know how to do that using and or radio button based on user!!!!.. we can easily implement AND OR Logic using sql query but  what we want is user is search either AND logic based press click AND radio button and vice versa same as OR logic

Comment: in the method declaration where I wrote `concatinator` just replace it with `fav_language`. Inside method replace `sqlquery += concatinator;` with `sqlquery += fav_language;` Thats all what you have to do.